# MonadRandom m => [g (m a)] -> m [g a]

Tags: haskell, monads

`g a` is a concrete type, I am thinking of doing `[g (m a)] -> [m (g a)] ->  m [g a]`, and I know the last step can be done with `sequence :: Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)`. How would I achieve the first step?

Comment: Does `traverse sequence` work?

Comment: With no constraints on `g` this is impossible. How do you turn `g (m a)` into `m (g a)`? It depends on what `g` is.

Comment: g is actually LEdge from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.6.0.0/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html#t:LEdge

Comment: So @Ryan's suggestion should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
sequenceLEdge :: Functor f => LEdge (f a) -> f (LEdge a)
sequenceLEdge (l, r, act) = fmap (\v -> (l, r, v)) act
```

Probably there should be `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances for triples and larger tuples so you don't need to write this by hand, but there aren't for now, so...